# PHP-FPM performance tuning - bursts of traffic

Tags: php, laravel, performance

I have a web application written in Laravel / PHP that is in the early stages and generally serves about **500 - 600 reqs/min**.   We use Maria DB and Redis for caching and everything is on AWS.

For events we want to promote on our platform, we send out a push notification (mobile platform) to all users which results in a roughly 2-min long traffic burst that takes us to **3.5k reqs/min**

At our current server scale, this completely bogs down the application servers' CPU which usually operate at around **10% CPU**.  The Databases and Redis clusters seem fine during this burst.

Looking at the logs, it seems all PHP-FPM worker pool processes get occupied and begin queuing up requests from the Nginx upstream.

We currently have:

- **three** m4.large servers (2 cores, 8gb RAM each)
- dynamic PHP-FPM process management, with a max of **120 child processes** (servers)on each box

My questions:

1) Should we increase the FPM pool?  It seems that memory-wise, we're probably nearing our limit

2) Should we **decrease** the FPM pool?  It seems possible that we're spinning up so many process that the CPU is getting bogged down and is unable to really complete any of them. I wonder if we'd therefore get better results with less.

3) Should we simply use larger boxes with more RAM and CPU, which will allow us to add more FPM workers?

4) Is there any FPM performance tuning that we should be considering? We use Opcache, however, should we switch to static process management for FPM to cut down on the overhead of processes spinning up and down?

Comment: Any bits of inefficient code you might be able to tune up?

Comment: @Reed we’ve optimized as much as we can at this point, which is why we’re assessing the fpm aspect

Comment: You can always increase the pool size, at least temporarily before a promotion happens, you can also add more servers to your scaling group, or enable auto-scaling (if the burst is not faster than the rate that AWS can boot up instances)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are too many child processes in relation to the number of cores.

First, you need to know the server status at **normal** and **burst** time.

1) Check the number of php-fpm processes.

```
ps -ef | grep 'php-fpm: pool' | wc -l
```

2) Check the **load average**. At 2 cores, 2 or more means that the work's starting delayed.

```
top
htop
glances
```

3) Depending on the service, we start to adjust from twice the number of cores.

```
; Example
;pm.max_children = 120       ; normal) pool 5, load 0.1 / burst) pool 120, load 5  **Bad**
;pm.max_children = 4    ; normal) pool 4, load 0.1 / burst) pool 4, load 1
pm.max_children = 8    ; normal) pool 6, load 0.1 / burst) pool 8, load 2  **Good**
```

> load 2 = Maximum Performance 2 cores

---

It is more accurate to test the web server with a load similar to the actual load through the apache benchmark(ab).

```
ab -c100 -n10000 http://example.com

Time taken for tests:   60.344 seconds
Requests per second:    165.72 [#/sec] (mean)
 100%    880 (longest request)
```

Comment: This is decent advice. 120 processes can be a lot. Starting from the amount of cores and test-wise scaling up untill everything grinds to halt is a decent optimization strategy.

Comment: thanks for this answer!  I just want to clarify:  i have 125 max servers, 25 start servers. The first PHP log we got on one of the boxes during the burst was: `[pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 32 total children`.

Comment: Also, when you say `Check the load average. At 2 cores, 2 or more means that the work's starting delayed.` . Do you mean, check the CPU usage?

Comment: 'CPU usage' and 'load average' are different.   https://www.tecmint.com/understand-linux-load-averages-and-monitor-performance/